# Return update error from SQL Server and catch it in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-update, try-catch

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server to update a patient shift record. To do this, you must verify that the `dniPaciente` exists in the databases. If it exists, it updates it, otherwise, it should show an error message indicating that the `dniPaciente` has not been found.

I already tried the following way, however it has not worked for me to throw an error message.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sobreTurno(@dniDelPaciente VARCHAR(8) ,@nu evaFecha DATE,
@nuevaHoraInicio TIME,@nuevaHoraFin TIME)
AS 
BEGIN TRY  
IF EXISTS (SELECT dniPaciente FROM Turno WHERE dniPaciente=@dniDelPaciente)
    UPDATE Turno
       SET [fecha]=@nuevaFecha, 
          [horaInicio]=@nuevaHoraInicio,
          [horaFin]=@nuevaHoraFin
     WHERE dniPaciente=@dniDelPaciente 
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
  PRINT('¡dniPaciente not found in the DATABASE!')    
END CATCH
```

The error thrown in SQL Server should be shown in the catch clause of Java.

```
try {

    CallableStatement sobreTurno = conexionBBDD.getConexionBBDD().prepareCall("{call sobreTurno(?,?,?,?)}");

    sobreTurno.setString(1, ventanaAsignacionSobreTurno.getDniPaciente());
    sobreTurno.setDate(2, new Date(ventanaAsignacionSobreTurno.getDateChooser().getTime()));
    sobreTurno.setTime(3, this.horaInicio);
    sobreTurno.setTime(4, this.horaFin);
    
 sobreTurno.execute();
 
} catch (Exception exeptionBBDD) {               
  //here I need to show the error message thrown from SQL SERVER                
}
```

Comment: For me it looks like you have mixed up the conditions: " If it exists, it updates it", but in the code IF NOT EXISTS then UPDATE

Comment: its true, you are right. I have already changed it but still it has not been able to throw me the error.

Comment: I guess, you can try to use RAISEERROR- functionality  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You aren't throwing an error? You are printing it? To throw it, use the keyword `throw` (instead of print).

Comment: You are EATING the error in your procedure - your application has no way of knowing what happened. You could rethrow the error. But your procedure consists of a single update statement - so why are you catching it at all? Why does your udpate need to be in a try/catch block? Think about what your code does - don't blindly follow a pattern if it does not apply.

Comment: `ELSE THROW 50000, '¡dniPaciente not found in the DATABASE!', 0;` Do not use a `TRY/CATCH` block

Comment: brilliant. It has worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The correct stored procedure is as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sobreTurno(@dniDelPaciente VARCHAR(8) ,@nuevaFecha DATE,
@nuevaHoraInicio TIME,@nuevaHoraFin TIME)
AS  
IF EXISTS (SELECT dniPaciente FROM Turno WHERE dniPaciente=@dniDelPaciente)
    UPDATE Turno
       SET [fecha]=@nuevaFecha, 
          [horaInicio]=@nuevaHoraInicio,
          [horaFin]=@nuevaHoraFin
     WHERE dniPaciente=@dniDelPaciente 
 ELSE THROW 50000, '¡dniPaciente not found in the DATABASE!', 0;
```